# UIWebView does not fill 4 inch retina

Tags: ios, uiwebview

My app has a uiwebview works great on non-retina and 3.5 inch retina, however on Iphone 5 a.k.a 4 inch retina, it doesnt fill the screen , there is a gap between webview and tabbar.

[image]

tried this, it doesnt work

```
myview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;//myview is the webview
myview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

also tried this:
[image]
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,
Mord

Comment: Probably wanted `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`. `autoresizingMask` is a single `NSUInteger UIViewAutoresizing`, you combine different values as part of [bit mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)), so the code you posted overwrites whatever you've set at IB.

Comment: if you add the view with "addSubview" it might not adapt to the larger frame. Try to set: myview.frame=self.view.frame

Comment: @A-Live yes it overwrites it but when I remove `autoresizingMask` code and leave the IB settings like above it doesnt change anything, gap is still there

Comment: @Sten no I dont add it as a subview in code, I just added a webview to view in IB, then set the `delagete` and in `viewdidload` call this `[myview loadRequest:request];` it works.

Comment: It should fill it's superview, not actual view of the viewController, make sure the superview size is correct for 4in display (if you select the root view at IB you'll be able to select its size at attributes inspector, when you select another root view size all frames are updated depending on their masks and constraints).

Comment: @A-Live I have tried all options (free, 3.5 , 4) nothing have changed, first I thought maybe `self.view` is not resizing for 4 inch, it stays 3,5 so webview fills only 3.5, `NSLog(@"width=%f height=%f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);` gives `width=320.000000 height=548.000000`

Comment: And what is the size of webview ? If you create new project and add subview at any xib, disable automatic layout, select all autoresizing options for the subview and switch to 4in root view size, the subview should be resized. It makes me think that you are either setting somewhere 3.5in frame to webview or it is autoresized but the html content is designed for 3.5in and doesn't respect larger webview.

Comment: @A-Live I was just trying to get webview frame size, it actually re-sizes to view frame size nothing wrong with webview,I feel like stupid now , it is the document inside of the webview giving that shade/shadow, documents is not resizing to 4 inch screen

Comment: I found this question while searching on a similar problem...maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552416/uiwebview-full-screen-size