# UIWebview full screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am trying to display a pdf in a UIWebview using the entire screen of the device, except the status bar and top bar. So far, I created `IBOutlet UIWebview *webview;` in my .h file. I connected the webview in my storyboard and wrote the following code in my .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];

    webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    webview.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    webview.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    [webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Chart" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [webview loadRequest:request];

    [self.view addSubview:webview];

}
```

The pdf displays correctly in my 3.5 inch, but in my 4 inch display, the bottom is cut off. This is even more noticeable when I rotate to landscape view. About 33% of the screen is not used at all. How can I fix this? I know it must have something to do with the UIWebview dimensions in my code above (`webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];`), but is there a better way to simply display the webview on the entire screen, without specifying a specific screen height and width?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One cheap thing to do would be to set the frame of the webview in  overriding - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

the advantage of doing it here, is that the size and orientation of the view has already been determined here, and you can get an accurate measurement.

Comment: I added this code, but there is an error: "Assigning to 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect') from incompatible type 'int'...

Comment: I just did - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 
    webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, the reason it worked is because you corrected CGRectmake to CGRectMake, not because it was changed to initWithFrame.

Comment: Edited my answer, in case someone else looks at it.

Comment: Thanks, man! I was looking for this solution for 2 days and that did it perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

**Using Auto Layout**

Be sure the "Constrain to margins" option is not checked, all constrain values are 0:

[image]

And your webview is a first child of your main view:

[image]

**Without Auto Layout**

Change webview autosizing connections:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of headache dealing with compatibility of iOS6, 7 and different screen sizes, I use this one:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.webview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
   // More setting your webview here

   // Set webview to full screen
   self.view = self.webview;

   [self.webview loadRequest:aRequest]; 
}
```

Comment: When you are replacing the controller's view property, you can prevent it from being created in the first place by assigning self.view in the loadView method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working correctly for me by selecting the `Reset to Suggested Constraints` under the `Resolve Auto Layout Issues` menu. 
[image]